# 'Invalid column name' from within a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I wrote a stored procedure to insert future dates (excluding Sat and Sun) into a permanent table. The routine uses just one temp table. The purpose of this post is not to critique the Stored Procedure. Although, I am certain it could be improved. However, the purpose of this post is to analyze why the stored procedure is throwing these errors when called under one set of circumstances and not others.

1 - Here are the errors I receive

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure MAKE_FUTURE_DATES, Line 25
Invalid column name 'tdate'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure MAKE_FUTURE_DATES, Line 31
Invalid column name 'wday'.
```

2 - Here is the stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MAKE_FUTURE_DATES] (@STARTDATE DATE)
AS
BEGIN
-- We need to populate FUTURE_DATES (table) with forward looking dates (week days only) 
-- We do not consider/exclude holidays here. We just exclude Sat/Suns

-- Temp table to hold the dates and days of the week
    CREATE TABLE #TMP_DATES(
        [tdate] [date] NULL,
        [wday] [varchar](10) NULL,  
        )

    -- To generate 'enough' future dates loop up to 1199 days in the future
    -- and insert dates that start with the current date and increase with each loop

    DECLARE @Loop INT
    SET @Loop = 0
    WHILE @Loop < 1200
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #TMP_DATES (tdate) VALUES (DATEADD(weekday,@Loop,@STARTDATE))   
        SET @Loop = @Loop + 1
    END

    -- Now update the wday column with the weekday name so we can get rid of
    -- Sat/Sun in the next step

    UPDATE #TMP_DATES
    SET wday = UPPER(LEFT(DATENAME(dw,tdate),3))

    -- Get rid of Sat/Sun
    DELETE FROM #TMP_DATES WHERE wday = 'SAT' or wday = 'SUN'

    -- Now clear the final destination table
    TRUNCATE TABLE FUTURE_DATES

    -- Insert the weekday dates into future_dates

    INSERT INTO FUTURE_DATES (fdate,wday)
    SELECT tdate,wday FROM #TMP_DATES

    DROP TABLE #TMP_DATES
```

3 - I have been calling the above stored procedure within another stored procedure as a SQL Server task in the background (via the SQL Server job scheduler) for about 6 months without any errors or problems. More recently, I created a new stored procedure, let's call it 'ABC', that calls a stored procedure that calls MAKE_FUTURE_DATEs.

4 - Here is the part I am trying to solve. When ABC is invoked as a SQL Server task in the background (via the SQL Server job scheduler) it throws the errors every time (which is daily) and the results are not produced/it crashes. When I first start up SQL Server Management Studio and run ABC it sometimes throws the error the first time. The second time in this sequence and all subsequent times it does not throw the error. Also, keep in mind that the stored procedure that has been calling MAKE_FUTURE_DATES for 6 months is still quite happy with no errors.

I am looking for suggestions on how to debug this or what to look for. Particularly how can it throw the error sometimes and not others?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code that you've posted looks fine to me.  Is this the complete code?

The only thing that comes to mind is that your "ABC" stored procedure also has a temp table called #TMP_DATES.  The temp table in ABC would then also be available in the scope of the called stored procedure.

However, if that were the case, you should get a different error when you called `CREATE TABLE #TMP_DATES` in the called procedure.

Comment: thanks for the responses. I intentionally drop #TMP_DATES at the end of the procedure. Please correct me if wrong but that would take the table and it's columns completely out of circulation/visibility? If yes, then could this be a different problem?

Comment: If ABC procedures calls this procedure, and ABC procedure also has a a temp table called #TMP_DATES, you will have a conflict, as the scope of that temp table will be shared with this procedure.  This conflict will happen before the drop statement.  Also, you didn't answer the question whether this is this the complete code, or if you omitted part of it for brevity.

Comment: What I posted was the complete code for MAKE_FUTURE_DATES the stored procedure that creates #TMP_DATES and populates FUTURE_DATES. I did not post the stored procedure that calls MAKE_FUTURE_DATES because it is very lengthy and, I think, not germane given the call is so simple. Since my last response here I created a recurring SQL Server Job that calls MAKE_FUTURE_DATES each day, a few hours before the 'ABC' stored procedure calls it indirectly. Now the higher level invoking stored procedure works w/o error. Calling the SPROC posted above once first fixes the problem. But I would like to fix it

Comment: Does the ABC proc contain a temp table called "#TMP_DATES"?  Even if it does, I'm at a loss as to how this could fail with the error as posted, but it would at least clear up that question of a possible scope conflict.

Comment: As was mentioned above, the scope of the temporary tables is more that the single SP but the current session. If you don't want such crashes simply change the name of the table in the your _MAKE_FUTURE_DATES_ SP to something unique (ex. `#TMP_DATES_REFILL`).

Among this, you can receive a semi-crash (table `FUTURE_DATES` full of `NULL` values) if the input parameter `@STARTDATE` was supplied as `NULL` - no check is made for it. Simply add the part of code like `set @STARTDATE = isnull(@STARTDATE, getdate())` to avoid this issue.

Comment: @PhilSandler thx and I found it!!! INVOKE_PHASE_FUTURES_N (no #TMP_DATES) calls MAKE_DATE_MASTER_FUTURE (no #TMP_DATES) but MAKE_DATE_MASTER_FUTURE calls both MAKE_FUTURE_DATES (posted above) and MAKE_FUTURE_HOURS. Both of these last two had #TMP_DATES tables. I changed one of them. Ill know for sure later today when it runs.

Comment: Good grief, it still bombed today even after the fix. I am at a loss.

Comment: In the end, I did find temp tables stepping on each other. This now works splendidly. thx all.

Answer (score 1):

Temp tables have a scope greater than just one procedure.

So you can create a temp table in uspProc1...and if in uspProc1, you call uspProc2, uspProc2 "can see" the temp table you created.

Make sure you provide unique names to your #temp tables.

Below is an example demonstrating the point.

```
IF EXISTS 
    (
    SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
    WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = N'PROCEDURE' and ROUTINE_SCHEMA = N'dbo' and ROUTINE_NAME = N'uspProc001'  
    )
BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspProc001]
END


GO

CREATE Procedure dbo.uspProc001 (
@Param1 int
)
AS

BEGIN


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TableOne') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #TableOne
end


CREATE TABLE #TableOne
( 
SurrogateKey int , 
NameOf varchar(12)
)

Insert into #TableOne ( SurrogateKey , NameOf ) select 1001, 'uspProc001'

Select * from #TableOne

EXEC dbo.uspProc002 

Select * from #TableOne

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TableOne') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #TableOne
end


END


GO




IF EXISTS 
    (
    SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
    WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = N'PROCEDURE' and ROUTINE_SCHEMA = N'dbo' and ROUTINE_NAME = N'uspProc002'  
    )
BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspProc002]
END


GO

CREATE Procedure dbo.uspProc002 
AS

BEGIN

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TableOne') IS NOT NULL
begin
    Insert into #TableOne ( SurrogateKey , NameOf ) select 2001, 'uspProc002'
end



END


GO










exec dbo.uspProc001 0
```